# How to report on todays in progress tasks?

Tags: reporting

I am stuck in strange problem, i have created a report on tasks and events but that report is not puling today's in progress tasks.

Below are the filters for the report.  Even if there are tasks due today, report is not showing, it is showing only completed tasks for today.  Please help.

[image]

Comment: Is the date field "Date" the correct field to be evaluating?  Due Date (ActivityDate) is just the assigned date.  Is your "Date" field updating on completion?

Comment: Maybe try changing the filter to "Contains" instead of equals. Also have you tried running the report. Sometimes the preview won't show results but after running the report it will display results. You could also check at the top of the report preview to see if "Show Details" is checked.

Comment: @BlairKristin I have checked filters using Contains but it still not working, I have even checked role hierarchy and permission sets but no luck.  I just cant show in progress tasks in report, however I am able to show today's completed tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, It was a silly mistake, I was using wrong report type  "Activities with Contacts", therefore report was pulling only records which are associated with contacts, I have created new report type Users with Activities and now it is working fine.